# Validate true between multiple mysql rows with php

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL database:

```
date       | avl
-----------------
2014-12-22 |  6
2014-12-23 |  3
2014-12-24 |  0
2014-12-25 |  2
```

I am using following query to get the data from MySQL database:

```
$check_in_date = $con->real_escape_string($check_in_date);
$check_out_date = $con->real_escape_string($check_out_date);
$results = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE avl > 0 AND date BETWEEN '$check_in_date' AND '$check_out_date' ORDER by avl DESC");
if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        $avl = $row['avl'];
        $date = $row['date'];
    }
}
```

This query only skip the row with 0 value in avl column. But I want it to return false if any of the row having 0 and true on not having 0 in any of the row between the $check_in_date and $check_out_date.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$check_in_date = $con->real_escape_string($check_in_date);
$check_out_date = $con->real_escape_string($check_out_date);
$results = $con->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE avl > 0 AND (date BETWEEN '$check_in_date' AND '$check_out_date') ORDER by avl DESC");
if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        $avl = $row['avl'];
        $date = $row['date'];
    }
}
```

Use bracket ()  in avl > 0 and between condition

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
  $check_in_date = $con->real_escape_string($check_in_date);
  $check_out_date = $con->real_escape_string($check_out_date);
  $results = $con->query(
  "SELECT date,
   CASE  WHEN avl > 0 THEN 'true'
   ELSE 'false' END as  myavl
 FROM table_name WHERE date BETWEEN  '$check_in_date' AND '$check_out_date' ORDER by avl DESC");
  if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $avl = $row['myavl'];
    $date = $row['date'];
      }
    }
```